# Can I open/write SQLite files on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlite

I want to create a web application that executes the command below on a SQLite file the user would upload:

```
sqlite3 input.sqlite .dump | sqlite3 output.sqlite
```

The user would then be able to download the "cleaned" database file.

Is it possible to create such an application using Google AppEngine? If not, is it possible on any other free hosting service?

*Rationale: The open source "Anki" software uses an SQLite database as a file format. File "corruption" is very frequent because many people move the files around [etc](http://ankisrs.net/docs/DeckErrors.html#_causes). In 90% of cases, it is fixed by the simple line above, but most people are not confident enough to install sqlite, so I want to create a webapp that will do it for them.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you

- can't execute system commands
- and don't have write access to the filesystem in GAE

But you can try Google Cloud Instances instead, or use them with Appengine

Comment: Incorrect - you have access to the file system, you just can't write to it.

Comment: What about the read part? I need to read a SQLite db file uploaded by admin to blobstore. Users download this db file as is.

Comment: Depends on SQLite client. If you have a pure Python/Java/Go client, that doesn't require anything to be installed, and doesn't use any system sutff, then there is a big chance that it will work